# Existence of a solution of $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla u = 0 \text{ in } \Omega $

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If we have the follwing PDE
$$\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla u =  0 \text{ in } \Omega $$
$$u=g(x,y) \text{ on } \partial\Omega $$

where $\mathbf{v}$ is a constant velocity field and $\Omega$ is a "nice" bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What could be the problem with the existence of a solution? The only thing I can think of is that if $\mathbf{v}=0$, then any function that satisfies $u=g(x,y)$ satisfies the BVP so the solution is not unique but I don't see any problems with existence?

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is what kind of regularity you expect from your solution especially on $\bar{\Omega}$.

For example let's take $v=(1,0)$  that means $u_x(x,y)=0 \Rightarrow u(x,y)=u(y)$. If the boundary condition is nontrivially dependent on $x$ you will run into problems.

The same holds true for other choices of $v$ the problem appears just in another direction. The problem is overdetermined and solutions exist just for very special choices of $g$ (fitting to $\Omega$).

Comment: Yes indeed! But do you also notice a problem for general vectors $v$?

Comment: I added a remark.